# Error in reading from json file with multiple dicts

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary, malformed

I have a json file that contains at least 30 000 dicts. It can be found here:

http://openxcplatform.com.s3.amazonaws.com/traces/nyc/downtown-west.json

I have scourged through the internet and found that this brought me closest to what I need, as I need to read through the json file one by one, input the dicts as an actual dict into a list:

```
with open("test.json") as data_file:
    for x in data_file:
        json.dumps(it.append(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

I tested this code and it worked for the most part. I tested with the first 2000 elements but, once I test the entire file, I receive this error:

```
  File "converter.py", line 58, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "converter.py", line 34, in main
    json.dumps(it.append(ast.literal_eval(x)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 80, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 63, in _convert
    in zip(node.keys, node.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 62, in <genexpr>
    return dict((_convert(k), _convert(v)) for k, v
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 79, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')
ValueError: malformed string
```

Anyone know why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2):

First, the file is not JSON formatted, but [JSON-lines](http://jsonlines.org/).

Second, you don't want to read JSON data with `ast.literal_eval`, since it 1) is very insecure, 2) is not a JSON parser and throws an error, when it sees `false` or `true`.

Use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).

Answer (score 1):

You dont' want to use `json.dumps` as that converts a dict to JSON. You are doing the reverse - reading JSON and converting to dict. You need to use `json.loads()` for that:

```
it = []
failures = []

with open('you_file.json') as f:
  for line in f:
    try:
      it.append(json.loads(line))
    except Exception:
      failures.append(line)

print 'Parsed {0} lines'.format(len(it))
print 'Failed {0} lines'.format(len(failures))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that using [TypeError: expected string or buffer in Google App Engine's Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223525/typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer-in-google-app-engines-python) helped in getting the program to behave properly. Using only json.loads gave me a typeerror.